# Has anyone managed to replace a screen on a Sony PRS-T1?

Tags: sony-prs-t1, sony

I dropped my PRS-T1 and the screen cracked (one-third of the screen diagonally still works), so the electronics is still functioning.  Replacement screens were available on eBay from the far-east but with no instructions.   Before risking ordering one, I stripped down my T1.  The screen appears to be heavily glued to a skeleton metal chassis... I am presuming I'd need some special heating jig or solvent to remove it... and so I gave up.  Is there any chance of reviving this or should I just bin it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this thread on [Mobileread](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=220557), it also has a link where you can download the service manual.

There is also a video guide on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqbYWHJk8Tk).

Please note that I don't own this ereader and that this is only the result of a quick web search, so I can't help you further.

Comment: Very good - you found my thread on MobileRead :-)  ISTR the service manual was not a lot of use to a home-repairer.  The Youtube video is something new and far more useful I think so cheers for that. I am now inspired to have a go, assuming the replacement screens are still available... will report back one way or another.

Comment: I have now ordered a replacement screen from Hong Kong (£21)... interesting that the guy in the video couldn't get the screen unstuck either and just cracked/smashed it off and cleaned up the mess!